# MySQL Duplicate entry, but a wrong string

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to duplicate some rows with a new number for *editie_id*
And I'm getting the following, weird duplicate entry error

> ### 1062 - Duplicate entry '2042-0-5085-143' for key 'werknemer_id'

This is the code I'm trying to execute

```
INSERT INTO antwoorden
(score, werknemer_id, coach_id, vraag_id, editie_id)
SELECT score, werknemer_id, coach_id, vraag_id, 143
FROM antwoorden WHERE werknemer_id = 2042
```

This is what the werknemer_id field looks like:

[image]

I can't imagine how the error can throw in this weird string tied together with "-".

#### Table Indexes

```
ALTER TABLE `antwoorden`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `werknemer_id`     (`werknemer_id`,`coach_id`,`vraag_id`,`editie_id`),
ADD KEY `revisie_id` (`editie_id`),
ADD KEY `vraag_id` (`vraag_id`),
ADD KEY `coach_id` (`coach_id`);
```

## Solution

I was looking at the insert query, but my select query was not refined enough.
I was getting multiple results, the solution is this query

```
INSERT INTO antwoorden (score, werknemer_id, coach_id, vraag_id, editie_id)
SELECT score, werknemer_id, coach_id, vraag_id, 143
FROM antwoorden WHERE werknemer_id = 2043 AND editie_id = 145
```

Comment: You have a combined index with the same name as the column.

Comment: Did you by any chance have `werknemer_id` with a `UNIQUE KEY`?

Comment: There is indeed an index on werknemer_id, coach_id, vraag_id, editie_id

Comment: ok, I think is easy if you provide us with the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX`

Comment: Run your query without the insert - only the select part. If you see any doubled data for your unique columns, you will run into this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That most probably cause you have a `UNIQUE INDEX` or `UNIQUE KEY` defined on those columns `(werknemer_id, coach_id, vraag_id, editie_id)`. Something like

```
CONSTRAINT `test_constraint` UNIQUE (werknemer_id, coach_id, vraag_id, editie_id);
```

Which means combined value of those columns must always be unique. In your case there already exists record which have values `2042-0-5085-143` and you are trying to insert the same value combination.

As can be seen from your edit, you indeed do have it

```
ADD UNIQUE KEY `werknemer_id`     (`werknemer_id`,`coach_id`,`vraag_id`,`editie_id`)
```

Comment: Yes there is an index on those fields. I don't really understand how this is a problem. Since i'm trying to create a new unique value by changing the editie_id to 143. Thanks for your time

Comment: well the thing is if you really need the `UNIQUE` or not. If you need it you have to check you dont insert duplicated tuples, if you dont need it remove the `UNIQUE` keyword from the index

Comment: Strange I can't find the combination of the error it's throwing, a select query with werknemer_id of 2042 and a editie_id of 143 has zero results.. so weird

Comment: Thank you, it's solved. solution added to question. PS/ someone downvoted my question? what's wrong with it.